# Kotlin Lambda function as a parameter

Tags: java, kotlin, future, completable-future

I am new to Kotlin and have difficulty understand the code below

```
private fun <T> catchAsyncExceptions(f: () -> CompletableFuture<T>) =
    try {
        f().get()
    } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
        throw e.cause!!
    }
```

So this function is called `catchAsyncExceptions`, its input parameter is a function called `f` which is `() -> CompletableFuture<T>`
So I would think that you use it by

```
catchAsyncExceptions(someFunctionThatTakesNoArgumentAndReturnsCompletableFuture)
```

However I see the usage is

```
override fun getUserInfo(userId: String) =
    catchAsyncExceptions {
        membersClient.getUserLocation(
            GetUserLocationRequest(userId)
        )
            .thenApply { response ->
                val (success, error) = parseSuccessAndError<GetUserLocationResponseResult.Success>(response.result!!)
                error?.let {
                    UserInfoResponse(
                        error = error.code
                        )
                    )
                } ?: run {
                    UserInfoResponse(
                        data = UserInfoResponseDto(
                            location = success?.success?.location.toString(),
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
    }
```

Note that

```
membersClient.getUserLocation(
            GetUserLocationRequest(userId)
        )
```

returns `CompletableFuture` type

I am especially confused why it was a curly bracket rather than a bracket

```
catchAsyncExceptions {
...
}
```

Comment: Look up “Kotlin trailing lambda”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin, when you have a lambda function as a parameter, the brackets are completely optional. You can rewrite the implementation as:

```kotlin
catchAsyncExceptions({
    membersClient.getUserLocation(
        GetUserLocationRequest(userId)
    )
        .thenApply({ response ->
            val (success, error) = parseSuccessAndError<GetUserLocationResponseResult.Success>(response.result!!)
            error?.let({
                UserInfoResponse(
                    error = error.code
                    )
                )
            }) ?: run({
                UserInfoResponse(
                    data = UserInfoResponseDto(
                        location = success?.success?.location.toString(),
                    )
                )
            })
        })
})
```

and this is a perfectly working code. For simplicity, the brackets are omitted to make the code more readable.

Comment: Pedantic: for brackets to be _completely_ optional, a lambda must be the only parameter, not just a parameter.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Seems like this is not the case: https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/04_functional/01_Higher-Order%20Functions

Comment: @DanyloMysak I am not sure what you mean. The relevant example there is `val mulResult = calculate(4, 5) { a, b -> a * b }`. My point was that it still needs brackets around `(4, 5)`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I see. What I meant was that brackets are not required around the lambda.

Comment: That's why I emphasized "completely".